# Performance in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, performance

My job is to develop a small 2D game in WPF. I saw a lot of cool games which are written in Silverlight. My quesion is now: Has WPF the same requirements for this purpose? Here (http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/b83db72d-bc0e-4423-88fc-99d7a77d60e5) I've found a really cool game in silverlight. I want to develop nearly the same in WPF. Are there any performance problems or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Silverlight is a (non-strict) subset of WPF.  Tools like Blend work fine (and are often heavily used) in WPF.  There *are* interesting performance issues that crop up occasionally, but that's true of any major UI framework.  WPF has the benefit of being accelerated by DirectX, so it tends to perform better than WinForms for many tasks.

Basically: have at, and ask questions later as you run into problems.

Also consider XNA.